# find the correct combination from multi list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if there is a better way to write the same code as following:

I would like to look for the combination in three lists, `a`, `b`, `c`, that each `a[i]`, `b[j]`, `c[k]` length larger than 10 and then return the total length. Is there any better way to code this?

```
from collections import namedtuple
a = ['a0', 'a1', 'a22'] 
b = ['b', 'b11111', 'b2'] 
c = ['', 'c', 'c333333333'] 

def func(**kwargs):
    nt = namedtuple('nt', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    for  x in kwargs['a']:
        for  y in kwargs['b']:
            for  z in kwargs['c']:
                if len(x) >= len(y) >= len(z) > 10:
                    return nt(a_header=x, b_header=y, c_header=c, all_len=len(x) + len(y) + len(z))
    return ()

    #    it should return len('a22') + len('b11111') + len('c333')
```

Comment: could You give us some example , because the descriptions isn't clear.

Comment: and as guess, some function from the `itertools` will do what You want, just check this module.

Comment: Your question says "each a[i], b[j], c[k] length larger than 10", but your code has a different test. Which is it supposed to be? Also, if there are multiple solutions, it looks like you only want the first solution found. Is that correct?

Comment: Your question and expected result says different.  None of the items exceed 10 in length and yet you expected them to be returned? Is it an *accumulative* length i.e. `x + y + z > 10`?  Depending on the clarification the answer can vary greatly.

Comment: Also none of the keywords in the `return nt()` line would work.  What is the expected return structure?

Comment: sorry..my example is bad....but what i mean is x >= y >= z larger than some number

Comment: In your expected outcome, it doesn't meet your `x >= y >= z` criteria as `len('a22') < len('b11111')`.  In this particular case the lengths are `3, 6, 4`.  Also *what* is being compared to "some number"? `3 + 6 + 4 > 10`? Or `3 > 6` and `6 > 4` and `4 > 10`? You will need to clarify the exact criteria for us to be of help.

Comment: i want 3 >= 6 >= 10 > 10

Comment: That's not a valid expression though.  `3` is clearly smaller than `6` and yet you expected the result to be there.  Did you mean you were looking to have them in some sort of ascending order, so that `len(x)` is smaller than `len(y)`, and `len(y)` is smaller than `len(z)`, and `len(z)` is smaller than 10? In case there's any language misunderstanding, `>=` means greater than or equal to, which `3` clearly isn't greater than `6`.  You should also only be comparing two things at once.  `3 >= 6 >= 10 > 10` resolves to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will likely fail if `len(z) = 15` and `len(y)=13` for example because you have required `len(x) >= len(y) >= len(z) > 10`. Instead try:

```
def func(**kwarg):
    nt = namedtuple('nt', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    for  x in kwargs['a']:
        for  y in kwargs['b']:
            for  z in kwargs['c']:
                if len(x) > 10 and len(y) > 10 and len(z) > 10:
                    return nt(a_header=x, b_header=y, c_header=c, all_len=len(x) + len(y) + len(z))
return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `that each a[i], b[j], c[k] length larger than 10`...

Don't use nested for-loops.

Instead check every list separately (`kwargs['a']`, then `kwargs['b']`, then `kwargs['c']`) and find all the elements (positions of elements) with length greater than 10. The complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the total length of all lists.

Finally calculate all possible sums or yield sums one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Using *itertools.product* we can create all 3 way combinations of one item per list.  We can take these this list of products and filter them down to only ones who have `lens >= (3, 6, 10)`, respectively *`"i want 3 >= 6 >= 10" - OP`*.

```
from itertools import combinations

lista = [(x, y, z) for x, y, z in product(a, b, c)]
res = list(filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) >= 3 and len(x[1]) >= 6 and len(x[2]) >= 10, l))
print(*res)
```

or for a *one-line solution* use *list comprehension*

```
res = [(u, v, w) for u, v, w in product(a, b, c) if len(u) >= 3 and len(v) >= 6 and len(w) >= 10]
```

> ```
> ('a22', 'b11111', 'c333333333')
> ```

Comment: `itertools.product()` would have been my answer too.  But I have a feeling the criteria is not as simple as `(3, 6, 10)` given the latest series of comments.

Comment: @Idlehands `i want 3 >= 6 >= 10 > 10 ` Yeah I was reading along, and this would translate into multiple results but seeing as the desired output is 1 of 1 that meets `len(i[1]) == 3, [2] == 6, [3] == 10` I was deducing this was the comparison they wanted

Comment: That's not the point though.  I doubt they're specifically checking against `(3, 6, 10)` for `(x, y, z)` regardless of the operation.  If anything they are checking each element against each other, but the question is *what* exactly are they checking.

Comment: @Idlehands I agree, they are phrasing as if  they are comparing against eachother but also the comments mention 3, 6, 10 and when looking at potential outputs is what I mean if we compare the items len in that order we are going to produce a list of possibilities seeing as if we take that route we introduce `a0, a1, b2` as all being viable candidates for that outcome